# How to extend my menu bar so that it fits any page perfectly, even if the window was resized

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

So yea, the menu bar won't extend 100% horizontally. It's only going half the way on my computer screen. Also, I want it to fit any screen 100%, so when I decrease the screen width, I want it to adjust properly, not just get all messy looking. Also, any advice on the coloring would be appreciated. Thanks so much for any help you bring forth.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "HTTP://WWW.W3.ORG/tr/XHTML1/dtd/XHTML1-TRANSITIONAL.DTD">
<html>
    <head>
     <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
     <title>My Webpage</title>   
     <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        My Webpage</header>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="navMenu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <br class ="clearFloat" />
      </div>    
    </div>
    <section>  
    Blabalalbalblababad;lkjfas;dkljf;alksjdf;aklsjdfk;alsdjkl;jasdfkl;ajsdf
        a;kjldf;alksjdf;akljsdfa;klsdjf;alksdjfkl;asdjf;laksdfj;asdlkjf
        a;sdlkjf;kljasdlfk;jas;dlkjfakl;sdjfa;lskjdf
        ad;slkjf;laksjdf;lkajsdfkl;asjdfl;kajsdfk;ljasdfkljasdf
        al;kjdf;lakjsdf;lkjasdfklj;alksj;dfak;ljdfakl;jdfklaj;fdkla;
    </section> 
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
header{
    background: #00795f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
#navMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navMenu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
}
#navMenu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #43a286;
}
#navMenu ul li a {
    text-align:center;
    font-famil:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:32px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
#navMenu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:32px;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}
#navMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #357e68;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background:#265a4a;
    color: #000000;
}
#navMenu a:hover {
    color:#000000;
}
.clearFloat {
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
section{
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of math can be done.

I noticed that if I set the width of each main *li* in the nav to 100%, it would leave each to fit 100% of the viewport. However they would all be stacked upon one another like this:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
header{
    background: #00795f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
#navMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;


}
#navMenu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
}
#navMenu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #00aeef;
    width:100%;
}
#navMenu ul li a {
    text-align:center;
    font-famil:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:32px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
#navMenu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:32px;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}
#navMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #0076a3;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background:#0076a3;
    color: #fff;
}
#navMenu a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
.clearFloat {
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
section{
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="navMenu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Item</a></li> 
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <br class ="clearFloat" />
      </div>    
    </div>
    <section>  
    Blabalalbalblababad;lkjfas;dkljf;alksjdf;aklsjdfk;alsdjkl;jasdfkl;ajsdf
        a;kjldf;alksjdf;akljsdfa;klsdjf;alksdjfkl;asdjf;laksdfj;asdlkjf
        a;sdlkjf;kljasdlfk;jas;dlkjfakl;sdjfa;lskjdf
        ad;slkjf;laksjdf;lkajsdfkl;asjdfl;kajsdfk;ljasdfkljasdf
        al;kjdf;lakjsdf;lkjasdfklj;alksj;dfak;ljdfakl;jdfklaj;fdkla;
    </section>
```

So what I did was find out how many "Product" links you had and get that divided into 100%. In other words: 100% *divided by* how many "Product links". You have 5, so I set the width of each li to 20%

Here's your code: http://jsfiddle.net/DVJmS/40/

Comment: That one seems to break the code of the children li. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DVJmS/41/

Comment: So what I'm getting is that you adjusted it so that each li item takes up an equal amount of the horizontal distance, and since there's 5 of them, then each takes 20%. Am I correct?

Comment: Ok I see that it does sprread it horizontally across the page. However, when I adjust the window size, the  words of the headers of the menu bar converge... I want it to be like say at Nfl.com where when u resize the window, the structure of the page is maintained and nothing is affected. Also, now when I dropdown with the menu and hover over the list items only the surrounding of the word is shaded not the whole li width span.